# Build tables - Append a selected column

Tags: command-line, bash, paste

I have several tables (tab separation) as follow:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES 
1971 1     1   1000 
1971 1     2   1542 
....
```

All of them present the same three first column. In order to group all the data in one big table, I would like to append the last column of all my tables. I currently use `paste` command:

```
paste table1.txt table2.txt > table.txt
```

But, I would like to just append the last column. Anyone has an idea about how to do that?

For example, `table1.txt` is as follow:

```
1971 1 1 1000
1971 1 2 1541
1971 1 3 1245
```

`table2.txt` as follow:

```
1971 1 1 234
1971 1 2 457
1971 1 3 987
```

and the desired output shoulb be like `table.txt`:

```
1971 1 1 1000 234
1971 1 2 1541 457
1971 1 3 1245 987
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a minimal example of your input and your desired output. It's hard to understand what you want without that. \

Comment: @ terdon - I have edited a minimal example of the desired output, I hope my post is more clear now.

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks. In that case, my answer should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work to print the last field:

```
paste table1.txt <(awk '{print $NF}' table2.txt) > table.txt
```

Or, if you know the last field will always be the 4th:

```
paste file1 <(cut -f4 file2) <(cut -f4 file3)
```

That will print the last field of `table2.txt` and pass that as input to `paste`. You can add as many files as you need:

```
paste file1 <(cut -f4 file2) <(cut -f4 file3) <(cut -f4 file4)  <(cut -f4 fileN)
```